# iOS Swift 'message sent to deallocated instance' with notification

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit

I'm trying to add an observer to my class so that it accepts notifications from GameKit on authorization changes.

Here is the code for adding the observer and the method it should be calling

```
override init(){
    super.init()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: NSSelectorFromString("authenticationChanged:"), name: GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName, object: nil)
}

func authenticationChanged(notification:NSNotification){

}
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
2014-11-18 13:11:19.262 Name[8074:1078111] *** -[Name authenticationChanged:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x174423500
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object has been deallocated. You need to remove yourself as an observer in `deinit`:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Worked with deinit as it is swift. If you want to put example code I can select your answer as correct

Comment: This is the code that worked: deinit { NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self) } just add it to your answer and I'll select it. Thanks for the original tip